# VsVim settings save file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vim, settings, vsvim

I have VsVim and when I load my solution file, I always need to :set ignorecase and :set smartcase each time. I'd like to save these settings, but I can't find where VsVim stores its settings or how to save its settings.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This has recently changed:

- https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/wiki/faq

> How can I verify my .vimrc is loading?
>
> There are 2 non-standard vim settings that can be used to diagnose potential .vimrc load issues
>
> - vimrc – This setting will display the full path of the file which was loaded for the .vimrc
> - vimrcpaths – This setting will display the files and paths searched for .vimrc
>
> By default VsVim will look for a file named .vsvimrc, _vsvimrc, .vimrc or _vimrc file in the paths HOME, VIM and USERPROFILE
>
> As of now the commands supported in the .vimrc file are limited to those supported in command mode.

Comment: Thank you sehe. For future reference, :set will show you your vimrcpaths. Creating a simple text file and filling it with all :set commands worked nicely. Keep in mind VsVim comes with some default :set commands which you need to include in your new .vimrc file. It won't 'add' so much as entirely replace your settings.